# APPIUM : Having trouble in Appium while switching to webview while testing Salesforce1 android app on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

While I am trying to automate Salesforce1 app on my android version 4.4.2, the app gets installed, Clicks on accepting user agreement(I agree), then Clicks on login button. The context then switches to webview and thats where the problem arises.

Here is my code:

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
// import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Demo1 {

@Test
public void demoTest() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{

// AndroidDriver driver;

File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")); // path to Eclipse project
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/apk"); // path to <project folder>/Contact Manager
File app = new File(appDir, "com.salesforce.chatter.apk");// path to <project folder>/Contact Manager/ContactManager.apk

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,""); 
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot","true"); 
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "3204481ceddaa1d7");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.salesforce.chatter");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter");
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept")));

WebElement addContactButton = driver.findElement(By.id("com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept"));
addContactButton.click();

WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("com.salesforce.chatter:id/log_in"));
loginButton.click();

Thread.sleep(9000);

 TouchAction touch = new TouchAction(driver);
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextName);
  if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
       driver.context(contextName);

    } 
 } 

WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
username.click();
username.sendKeys("************");


WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
password.click();
password.sendKeys("***********");

WebElement loginButton1 = driver.findElement(By.id("Login"));
loginButton1.click();

}
}
```

Logs:

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk","appPackage":"com.salesforce.chatter","appActivity":"com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter","browserName":"","takesScreenshot":"true","platformName":"Android","version":"4.4.2","deviceName":"3204481ceddaa1d7"}}

info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)
warn: Converting cap takesScreenshot from string to boolean. This might cause unexpected behavior.
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : takesScreenshot, version
info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: Java version is: 1.8.0_45
info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
info: [debug] Set chromedriver binary as: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
info: [debug] Preparing device for session
info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
info: Retrieving device
info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
info: Found device 3204481ceddaa1d7
info: [debug] Setting device id to 3204481ceddaa1d7
info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 wait-for-device
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "echo 'ready'"
info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
info: [debug] Getting device API level
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
info: Device API level is: 19
info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: en
info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk" "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\com.salesforce.chatter" en
info: [debug] No strings.xml for language 'en', getting default strings.xml
info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk" "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\com.salesforce.chatter"
info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
info: [debug] Setting language to default
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 push "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\com.salesforce.chatter\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe
info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk AndroidManifest.xml
info: [debug] Set app process to: com.salesforce.chatter
info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk.
info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk
info: [debug] App already signed.
info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk
info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\zipalign.exe
info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\115530-16608-1ipilb4\appium.tmp
info: [debug] MD5 for app is c68403dd22fea8f87f4b2785ae30234a
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/c68403dd22fea8f87f4b2785ae30234a.apk"
info: [debug] Getting install status for com.salesforce.chatter
info: [debug] Getting device API level
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "pm list packages -3 com.salesforce.chatter"
info: [debug] App is installed
info: App is already installed, resetting app
info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "am force-stop com.salesforce.chatter"
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "pm clear com.salesforce.chatter"
info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
info: Starting App
info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
info: [debug] No matching processes found
info: [debug] Running bootstrap
info: [debug] spawning: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.salesforce.chatter -e disableAndroidWatchers false
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] json loading complete.
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "dumpsys window"
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"\/data\/local\/tmp","status":0}
info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":false,"status":0}
info: [debug] Getting device API level
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.salesforce.chatter/com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter"
info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.salesforce.chatter" and activity "com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter" to be focused
info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "dumpsys window windows"
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
info: [debug] Device is at release version 4.4.2
info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 19573.660 ms - 74 
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1 {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk","appPackage":"com.salesforce.chatter","appActivity":"com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter","browserName":"","takesScreenshot":true,"platformName":"Android","version":"4.4.2","deviceName":"3204481ceddaa1d7"},"app":"C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk","appPackage":"com.salesforce.chatter","appActivity":"com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter","platformName":"Android","version":"4.4.2","deviceName":"3204481ceddaa1d7"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1 200 8.267 ms - 796 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk","appPackage":"com.salesforce.chatter","appActivity":"com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter","browserName":"","takesScreenshot":true,"platformName":"Android","version":"4.4.2","deviceName":"3204481ceddaa1d7"},"app":"C:\Appium_Test\apk\com.salesforce.chatter.apk","appPackage":"com.salesforce.chatter","appActivity":"com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter","platformName":"Android","version":"4.4.2","deviceName":"3204481ceddaa1d7"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element {"using":"id","value":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept","context":"","multiple":false}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept","context":"","multiple":false}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept using ID with the contextId: multiple: false
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"status":0}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element 200 1050.164 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element/1/displayed {}
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:getAttribute",{"elementId":"1","attribute":"displayed"}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:getAttribute","params":{"elementId":"1","attribute":"displayed"}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getAttribute
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"true","status":0}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element/1/displayed 200 418.928 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element {"using":"id","value":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept","context":"","multiple":false}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept","context":"","multiple":false}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept using ID with the contextId: multiple: false
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.salesforce.chatter:id/mi_accept]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"status":0}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element 200 90.549 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element/2/click {"id":"2"}
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"2"}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element/2/click 200 672.368 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element {"using":"id","value":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/log_in"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/log_in","context":"","multiple":false}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.salesforce.chatter:id/log_in","context":"","multiple":false}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding com.salesforce.chatter:id/log_in using ID with the contextId: multiple: false
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.salesforce.chatter:id/log_in]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"status":0}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element 200 559.730 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element/3/click {"id":"3"}
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"3"}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"3"}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element/3/click 200 3647.621 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/contexts {}
info: [debug] Getting a list of available webviews
info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 3204481ceddaa1d7 shell "cat /proc/net/unix"
info: [debug] Available contexts: 
info: [debug] []
info: [debug] Available contexts: NATIVE_APP
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP"],"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/contexts 200 395.859 ms - 86 {"status":0,"value":["NATIVE_APP"],"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element {"using":"id","value":"username"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"id","selector":"username","context":"","multiple":false}]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"username","context":"","multiple":false}}
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding username using ID with the contextId: multiple: false
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.salesforce.chatter:id/username]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=android:id/username]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=username, INSTANCE=0]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding username using ID with the contextId: multiple: false
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.salesforce.chatter:id/username]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=android:id/username]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=username, INSTANCE=0]
info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}
info: [debug] Condition unmet after 1062ms. Timing out.
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.","origValue":"No element found"},"sessionId":"151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/151a20b1-698d-497f-baf1-190e64e838c1/element 500 1064.592 ms - 195
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, please post that, secondly remove this capability takesScreenshot, our log clearly shows that.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in Appium(Java)....You need to handle the contexts....below is an example of handling Login with Facebook webview. It worked for me....

```
Set<String> contextHandles = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String s : contextHandles) {
    System.out.println("Context : " + s);
//if context contains webview then set the webview context
    if (s.contains("WEBVIEW")) {

        //System.out.println("Set the Context NATIVE to WEBVIEW");
        driver.context(s);
    }
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']")).sendKeys(EMAIL);
//System.out.println("UserName Entered");
//sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='1']")).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
//System.out.println("Password Entered");
```